# How can I type special symbols on my Android device like ☺ or ♥ as a regular character?

Tags: keyboard, text-input, special-chars

How can I make special symbols on my Samsung Galaxy SII, like ☺ or ♥?

Comment: FYI the first character doesn't show up for me on ICS, so you should be careful when using these.

Comment: by hex subset: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/how-to-insert-unicode-characters-by-their-hex-codes-using-usb-keyboard-on-ics

Comment: You could also copy and pin them into your keyboard's clipboard if it has such a feature. GBoard, for example, has it

Answer (score 16):

These are actually Unicode characters you can easily reproduce on your computer:
[How can I get “WHITE SMILING FACE (U+263A)” with the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/59107/how-can-i-get-white-smiling-face-u263a-with-the-keyboard)

The Android platform supports unicode and all its characters, however the soft keyboard that comes with your Android ROM probably won't carry all your desired symbols.

When long clicking on some symbols/characters on your soft keyboard you will see the key pop-up expanding to give you an additional choice of symbols, then drag and release your finger to print them.

Installing some 3rd party keyboards (such as GO-Keyboard) will give you access to more symbols.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest, practical way is to Google Search the Unicode Names of these symbols and copy them (e.g. ☺ is [WHITE SMILING FACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm) and ♥ is [BLACK HEART SUIT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2665/index.htm)). If you need to do this often though, you'd want to get an 3rd party keyboard.

Comment: Can you recommend a keyboard that does it by hex code? I could only find https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.cwd.unicodekeyboard but it is paid. There are others that find the character to copy paste, but it's not very practical.

Answer (score 3):

There are dedicated Keyboards you can install. One of them is [SymbolsKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisters.textart.free)

See also (S2 relevant): [How to switch Input Method / keyboard?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25332/how-to-switch-input-method-keyboard)

Comment: I wish this had an Unicode hex input.

Answer (score 3):

Activate keyboard (e.g by perfoming any type action)

Go to symbols.

Long-press this button `•`; you will see these: `♥♣♠♦♪`.
When you long-press `*`, you can type `★`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to "Go to symbols"? Or is this something special and obvious to Samsung users? I tried to follow your steps on my HTC running ICS, but stuck on step 1.

Comment: I think its universal. I did it with my Lenovo. I have GBoard (the google keyboard) app already installed I don't know if it is required. Click the ?123 key on the bottom left corner to show more symbols. Then  click on the =/< key to show even more symbols. You will find the required dot on the first row

Answer (score 2):

I use google keyboard for texting. For this keyboard, u just need to go symbols, on bottom right, there's a straight vertical line | (like this o e) below the brackets. Press that and the heart shape will appear...

Answer (score 1):

make a note and save ★☆♥☏✹✃✈✉☺☻™✽ッツ♨✆ ★★★★★ ♥

Comment: Seems like a "feel free to copy these few I incuded here" for later copy/pasting. Generally not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm (still) using the average ICS (4.0.4) on a Motorola Atrix 2. If I go to the Symbols keyboards in the Standard Motorola keyboard input, and long press any symbol key, it will display a blue rectangle, showing the symbol, and whether there are other symbols available from that key. This is initially shown by an ellipsis (three dots: ...) to the bottom right of the symbol. If there are no other symbols, no ellipsis appears... Wait a bit longer and the other symbols will then be displayed in a new blue rectangle. Simply slide to the symbol you want. Most of the useful symbols are on the Second symbols keyboard, so press the [?123] key, then the [=\<] key, and Yes, the Heart (admittedly a black one) is under the • key.

Answer (score 1):

For new versions of Android, the easiest way I have found is to use [Character Pad - Symbols](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.husseinelfeky.characterpad&hl=en). It allows to add characters by

> Simply tap a character to copy it to your device's clipboard, open any other app, and paste it anywhere you like

It also has a search function to allow finding characters by their names.

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the app.

Answer (score 0):

If I tip the keyboard to horizontal then hold down the microphone key - I get emoticons as an option. (Samsung G4)