# How to switch Input Method / keyboard?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, keyboard, input-methods

I recently upgraded my Galaxy S2 from Android 2.x to 4.0.3.

I had, and still have, two keyboards installed & enabled - MultiLing Keyboard, and Swype.

In my previous ROM, long-pressing an input field let me switch keyboards. This method now stopped working, and the only way I found to switch them is via the setup menu.

Has the method to switch inputs changed in ICS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've activated an input field, you should see a keyboard icon in your notification area. Drag the notification bar down and tap on the notification saying `Select input method` and you should get the menu.

If this doesn't work, it's due to Samsung's modifications. At least the vanilla ICS has this option.

Comment: Thanks. I would never have searched there ... too bad they removed the hold-to-switch method.

Answer (score 2):

In all of my HTC phones, press & hold in the input area (text area) will show a "Input Method" prompt for switching IME.